# Flutter: unexpected space at the top of ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I have the following source code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, cardIndex) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Main Course',
                      style: kRestaurantMenuTypeStyle,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: menuCards[cardIndex].menuItems.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
                        return RestaurantMenuItem(
                          menuItem: menuCards[cardIndex].menuItems[itemIndex],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: menuCards.length,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, the `ListView.builder()` creates this extra space on top automatically. This is shown in the image below. That is the big white space between the 'Main Course' and 'Pancit Malabon' texts.

[image]

I don't understand why `ListView` does that. How do I remove the space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, the `ListView` scrolls close to the top of the screen and by default, `ListView` adds a padding to avoid obstructing the system UI. So a zero padding would remove the extra space.

> By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable
> extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's
> padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding
> property.

Source : [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#external-links:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20ListView%20will%20automatically%20pad,link)

Answer (score 46):

To avoid this behaviour of listview, **override** padding property with a **zero** [padding]

```
return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      itemCount: data.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {}
);
```

Comment: Just to note, there's a bug on iOS where you can't tap the top items if you do this. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114498

Comment: @OliverDixon you forgot to update this comment that this was user error with double scaffold, not in solution it self. It is not bugged nor it was

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by adding a `padding` to my list view like so:

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
  ...
),
```

I don't understand why the solution works. If someone can explain the bug, I can accept theirs as the correct answer.

Comment: Because its not a bug, its weird default behaviour of ListView...

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your listview with `MediaQuery.removePadding`

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: ListView(...),
)
```

Comment: Great solution to remove the paddings for widgets not exposing the padding property! I was struggled for 3hrs trying to remove unexpected paddings added by Flutter overlay from the CalendarDatePicker, this is excellent!

Comment: You can just put padding: ```EdgeInsets.zero``` now, no need for all the extra stuff.

Comment: This solution works perfectly

Comment: this solution is unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
              context: context,
              removeTop: true,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: ListView.builder(
this will remove any excess padding issue that is hard to solve in the listview.builder
```